# System.AssertException not allowing me to convert Leads into Opportunities

Tags: apex, managed-package, controller, opportunity

I'm trying to convert a lead into an opportunity (on a managed package), so no access to the triggers. I just want to know if there's a solution to an Assertion Failed.

This is part of the Error Message:

> rC_Giving.Opportunity_AfterInsert: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: null == opportunityGiving.Giving_Amount__c:

Is it the trigger that's causing this? Any way around it without fixing the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that what this error `null == opportunityGiving.Giving_Amount__c` is telling you is that you've not put an amount in for the Opportunity. Looks like you're perhaps using the NPSP and the opp is a donation of some kind? The managed package is treating that custom field as a required field.

Comment: That sucks, because Leads usually don't have an amount tied to them......Maybe if I create a field that maps to Giving Amount

Answer (score 2):

What I did was avoid validation rules from triggering upon conversion. That will trouble the data a bit, but at least I can create leads now.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @MohithShrivastava & Eric: This is a solution/work around, why wouldn't that be a valid answer ?